# How to avoid suck outs when squeezing cold callers

Tags: texas-hold-em, betting-strategy

I've had a few hands where I have say, KQ and the flop contains K rag Q. Clearly I am favourite here so tend to ram and jam on the flop, turn and river.

On a few occasions though, some short stacks cold call and then come over the top on the river and then villain wins with something like 22 hitting a 2 on the river. Due to the small bet, I can't really get a read, but such a hand is costly. Any idea how I should otherwise play it? I've seen many heroes in similar positions simply check on the river but this would have no effect here since villain would still throw in their last coin.

This is a 6 handed ring game with no ante and various positions for hero & villain. This is also the fast online variant (rush/snap/zoom etc) so hard to get a read on players without a pretty good memory!

Comment: Post specifics if you want advice.

Comment: There's no need to be so aggressive and hostile in your comments @RobbieDee. You're the one asking for advice, it makes it so much harder to give good advice when people have to ask for clarity and your response is 'OK I'll throw you a bone'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are either going to be way ahead or way behind on the flop.  You block KK and QQ, so the most likely hand that you are way behind is a set of rags.

You should be forcing hands like deuces to fold if you bet the flop and turn aggressively.  You can't help it if they continue when they shouldn't and suck out on the river.

You have to ask yourself what hands would they call two big bets with and then value bet the river.  You could probably be getting value from good one pair hands, but it seems unlikely that they would come over the top on the river if they have good showdown value.

I would pay close attention to the board texture here.  Could they be bluffing after missing a draw?  If any draws did get there by the river you have to consider folding.

If the board is really dry and they still come over the top there is a strong possibility that you are beat.  Top two pair is a good hand, but their line is really strong and they're representing a bigger hand.  I would probably only call here if I put them on a missed draw.

**tl;dr You can't avoid a suck out if someone continues when they shouldn't**

Answer (score 1):

Why is your default action to jam when you hit? As you said, this play is costly when it explodes, and put it this way, when you're jamming you're not getting called by worse.

A better approach would be to bet it normally and evaluate what your opponent does in response.

Comment: Question is not very clear

Comment: I know quite a few 'seasoned pros', I've been a high-end dealer for a very long time and have talked shop with many well known pros. Am I a pro? No of course not, however there are several ways to get a read. Everything the player does at a table, past hands, how they act, level of attention thy're paying, how they talk about the game can give you clues how they might play. Poker is not a game of isolated incidents in the long run, you HAVE to use everything together to build reads. So yeah a ram and jam 100% of the time is just wrong.